# Alias to remote SQL Server in local computer

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, database-connection

I have an application that uses SQL Server Express Edition. Unfortunately it can connect only to local instance. The problem is I have a remote instance bought from one of internet providers.

The question is, id there any possibility to make some kind of "local alias" for remote database? Maybe I can install another instance locally and perform some kind of mirror or replication (I can only install Express Edition as I have no funds for any other version)?

Comment: I'm confused. You don't need to install the *database engine* in order to be a client and connect to a remote server... What are you trying to do?

Comment: Never mind, I get it...Is "The application you have can only connect to a local instance." a correct interpretation?

Comment: do you mean that the connection string is hardcoded in your application to target localhost\sqlexpress ?

Comment: Correct, the application can connect only to local instance. I have no idea how it is realised (connection string hardcoded is a possible reason) and why, also I can't do anything about that. I simply need to connect to local instance and use remote data. In Oracle (which I know better) I would try to prepare views based on dbLinks - in SQL Server, I have no idea what to do... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to push this question as I am looking for the exact same thing. I have Microsoft Business Contact Manager installed and it only allows me to connect to local (local network) SQL Express instances... however I do have a SQL 2008 database instance available from an internet hosting service. Is there a tool/solution which would create some kind of a local node so BCM would see it as a local instance but the communcation would happen "in the background" with the remote database?